# check how many arrays have length greater than 0 in javascript and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to create a validation in my app.

What I have, is multiple lists with a toggle (true/false).

If the item is selected, it populates an array.

And I have a different array for each group.

Pretty much something like this:

```
$scope.selected = {
  group1: {
    values: []
  },
  group2: {
    values: []
  },
  group3: {
    values: []
  }
}
```

When I select something, let's say, from the list in group 1, $scope.selected changes to this:

```
$scope.selected = {
   group1: {
     values: [{cat: 1, id: 1},{cat:1, id:3}]
   }
}
```

The problem I've got is that I am trying to validate this.

What I need is to be able to display a message if multiple values arrays are greater than 0.

For instance if:

```
$scope.selected = {
   group1: {
     values: [{cat: 1, id: 1},{cat:1, id:3}]
   },
   group2: {
     values: [{cat: 2, id: 5},{cat:2, id:2}]
   }
}
```

a message should appear as I can't allow to submit multiple groups at once.

I know that I can have some sort of function that checks on the specific name for the groups, but I need something a bit more dynamic, as groups may (and will) increase at some point (ie. I will have more groups that the ones I have now).

Is there any way I can check that only one out of all my group arrays is not empty, and if multiple are not empty, I show something?

thanks and I hope it's clear enough

Comment: Working, minimal code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the object:

```
var count = 0;
for (var group in $scope.selected) {
   if ($scope.selected.hasOwnProperty(group) && group.values.length > 0) 
      count++;
}

if (count > 1)
   console.log("More than one group with values");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#filter` and `Object.keys(o)`

```js
const selected = {
   group1: {
     values: [{cat: 1, id: 1},{cat:1, id:3}]
   },
   group2: {
     values: [{cat: 2, id: 5},{cat:2, id:2}]
   }
};
const validSelected = {
   group1: {
     values: [{cat: 1, id: 1},{cat:1, id:3}]
   },
   group2: {
     values: []
   }
};

function validate(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>obj[k].values.length>0).length === 1;
}



console.log(validate(selected)); //false
console.log(validate(validSelected)); //true
```

Without **ES6** arrow :

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k){return obj[k].values.length>0).length === 1});
```

Comment: I am using CoffeeScript and the arrow function is a bit tricky to convert...can I have an example that doesn't use the arrow function please?